# Accessing .mdb files through nodejs

Tags: node.js, ms-access-2007, npm

I want to Access .mdb files and manipulate like insert / update using nodejs

Please suggest a library that would suite the need.

Thanks.

Comment: Is node's default file system library (http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) insufficient for your needs?

Comment: how to insert / update into file using sql syntax ?

Comment: This is just for the POC, Thanks.
Can you tell why you're preferring mongodb instead of MySQL ?

Comment: I searched this topic as a joke, anyways... To answer your last question. MongoDb can be run in a similar fashion as Access when we think about it';s portability. You can ship a project with the database right inside the directory structure HOWEVER, i'm assuming you are inheriting a legacy db and mongo is not a relational database so make sure that this is an option schema-wise ELSE maybe converting to MySQL will be a better option in the long run. But he is correct, you should be thinking about an alternative when working with node. I don't see a lot of support for MS access in nodejs.

Comment: @Mike Your comment provides no benefit to the discussion. If the poster had asked for recommendations two things would have happened: It would have received numerous MongoDB and CouchDB answers , and second it would have been closed as too subjective. He asked a perfectly reasonable question and not every project supports being able to replace an existing JET database regardless of how much we KNOW it's a bad choice. Pragmatic work vs. pie in the sky. There are many internal apps which still use Access for inventory tracking, CRM. And being able to expose a API to them is nice.

Answer (score 30):

Slightly different but node-adodb worked well for me for .accdb files:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-adodb

```
// Get the adodb module
var ADODB = require('node-adodb');
ADODB.debug = true;

// Connect to the MS Access DB
var connection = ADODB.open('Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\dbs\\my-access-db.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;');

// Query the DB
connection
    .query('SELECT * FROM [TestTable];')
    .on('done', function (data){
        console.log('Result:'.green.bold, data);
    })
```

Comment: This only works if you are running Windows. It throws errors on a mac or linux OS because it requires MSAccess Drivers. If you do not have Access installed on your Win OS you can install just the driver here for 2010 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: It's written in pure javascript. No node-gyp needed like node-odbc. Works perfectly!

Comment: It's nice when the question is answered and not criticised. There are numerous reasons to want to do this AND have no choice over replacing a JET database. This answer provides the solution to many database questions. I'm curious how it could be pure Javascript though. If it's true, then quite impressive accessing the ADO COM.

Answer (score 8):

This article describes the process for connecting PHP to an Access .mdb database:
http://www.sitepoint.com/using-an-access-database-with-php/

The process for Node.js is quite similar - it's just another ODBC data source.

You'll need a node ODBC package, such as:
<del>https://github.com/wankdanker/node-odbc</del>

https://github.com/markdirish/node-odbc/

Then you'll need to format your ODBC connection string. eg.

```
"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=MyDatabase; Uid=; Pwd=;"
```

Comment: Will it work like 
path = "/path/to/the/file.mdb";
`"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ="+path+"; Uid=; Pwd=;"`

Comment: It seems Dbq does support a path.

Comment: Also, if you are using this driver with a 64-bit application (eg Node.js 64-bit) to access an .mdb or .accdb file directly, you may have issues. If you do, the following may be relevant: MS Office usually installs Microsoft Access Driver 32-bit which is incompatible with 64-bit apps. You'll need to 1) uninstall MS Office 2) download & install the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable (x64) at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 3) install MS Office again

Comment: That sounds rather inconvenient

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is [OWIN module](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2013/02/access-ms-sql-from-nodejs-application.html) which is currently developed as [Edge.js](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/) by Mr Tomasz Janczuk.