# Issue connecting to ODBC with NodeJs and node-adodb module

Tags: node.js, odbc

I am  trying to create an application to connect to an ODBC.

I have a data source set up in ODBC Data Source Administrator 64 Bit.

I have 64 bit version of nodejs installed and i have a simple sample connection code from the node-adodb npm page.

However when I run the app I get an error:

> The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver
>   and Application

I'm trying to figure this out, but Im not sure why I am getting this error if the Driver is the ODBC Data source and the Appliation is my app and both of those are 64bit.

Is there something else that I am missing here?

The code I am using in my app.js:

```
var ADODB = require("node-adodb");
process.env.DEBUG = 'ADODB';


var connection = ADODB.open('cms');

connection
  .query('SELECT first 10 * FROM dsplit')
  .on('done', function(data) {
    console.log('result:', JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '));
  })
  .on('fail', function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Thank you,

Barry

Comment: Just to be sure: The ODBC driver is 64bit too? I'm asking, because I think that with some versions of windows you can use the 64 bit odbc admin tool to configure DSN using 32bit drivers too.. what would lead to the error you have shown.

Comment: Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426935/accessing-mdb-files-through-nodejs the comment of user bzuillsmith from Jul 30 '14 has some hints about access, bitness and node.js..

Comment: @erg - Yes, I have checked and it shows Platform 64bit. I will check out that link. Thank you.